# Where is the implementation of these interface methods?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

I am new to spring Boot and Hibernate and was going through the below post on the same: https://medium.com/@gustavo.ponce.ch/spring-boot-spring-mvc-spring-security-mysql-a5d8545d837d

I see the below methods declared in the interface but there is no implementation for any of these methods anywhere.

```
  @Repository("userRepository")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
     User findByEmail(String email);
}

@Repository("roleRepository")
public interface RoleRepository extends JpaRepository<Role, Integer>{
    Role findByRole(String role);

}
```

Can someone please explain where is the implementation for these methods and how is it working?

Comment: That's one of the things Spring does for you, it *generates* the implementation based on the method names.

Comment: @jonrsharpe that's why I mentioned, '_I am new to spring Boot and Hibernate_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Getting Started: Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) article:

> In a typical Java application, you’d expect to write a class that implements CustomerRepository. But that’s what makes Spring Data JPA so powerful: You don’t have to write an implementation of the repository interface. Spring Data JPA creates an implementation on the fly when you run the application.

If you dig deeper into the Sprign Data JPA framework you will find [`org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.html) and other classes that do the actual work. Normally you won't be using these.